# delphi11.3 Project--Deployment,it show black

Tags: delphi-11-alexandria

when I open delphi11.3 Project--Deployment ,it show black ,just like this:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MiEpo.png)

I've had this problem at delphi10.4,then I installed delphi11.3,but it doesn't work.how can I make it normal?Has anyone else encountered this issue?